# Showing/finding sumfunction

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I will try again asking my question: I have $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}x^n$, for x$\in$R. Then I have used wolframalpha finding the sum function: 
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D+%5Cfrac%7Bn*x%5E%7Bn%7D%7D%7Bn%2B1%7D
And with Maple I have reduced the sum function to:
$\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{ln(1-x)}{x}$ for |x|<1.
But how can I show it formally that this is the sum function?

Comment: "For $x \in \Bbb{R}$" your power series does not converge for $x > 1$.

Comment: Are you asking how to derive the closed form for the series, or are you asking how to determine for which real numbers it converges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $|x|<1$

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nx^n}{n+1}&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n-\frac1x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\\\\
&=\frac x{1-x}-\frac1x\int_0^x \sum_{n=1}^\infty t^n\,dt\\\\
&=\frac x{1-x}-\frac1x\int_0^x \frac{t}{1-t}\,dt
\end{align}$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: Thank you it makes sence

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: Hi Mark ! I know that you enjoy playing with bounds of logarithms. Yesterday, just for the fun ot it, I used some of them. Would you please have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3695080/limit-of-an-infinite-sum-with-natural-logarithm/3695300#3695300 and tell me what you think. Thanks & cheers.